# How to figure out if a query result contains exactly some items

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I want to figure out if a query result contains exactly some items. I explain:
I have a profile_stores table that contains the managed stores of each profile
Let's say i have 5 profiles P1-> P5 and 4 stores s1 -> s4
and my table contains

```
profie  |  store
------------------
    P1  |  S1
    P2  |  S2
    P3  |  S3
    P2  |  S2
    P1  |  S2
    P1  |  S3
    P4  |  S1
    P5  |  S2
```

Now, we have the following profile 1 P1 is managing the stores S1 and S2 and S3

```
=> 
    P1(S1,S2,S3)
    P2(S1,S2)
    P3(S4)
    P4(S1)
    P5(S2)
```

What i need to know now is how can i set my query to get the profiles that are managing simultanously and only the stores S1 and S2 ?

Ps: In my case the query should return only P2

Any Help will be appreciated

Comment: I'm finding this bit a little hard to understand: _What i need to know now is how can i set my query to get the profiles that are managing simultaneously and only the stores S1 and S2 ?_ P2 only has S2, so not sure how it's in the result,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GROUP BY`-solution:

```
select profile
from tablename
group by profile
having count(distinct store) = 2
   and min(store) = 'S1'
   and max(store) = 'S2'
```

Alternative solution:

```
select profile
from tablename t1
where not exists (select 1 from tablename t2
                  where t1.profile = t2.profile
                    and t2.store not in ('S1', 'S2', ...))
group by profile
having count(distinct store) = 2 (or 3 or 4...)
```

Comment: How would you expand this method to be able to search for profiles that are linked to exactly 3 different stores instead of 2?

Comment: I'd go with another solution in that case! Will edit - but promise to upvote if you like it!

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT DISTINCT profile FROM profile_stores
WHERE profile IN (SELECT profile FROM profile_stores WHERE store = 'S1')
  AND profile IN (SELECT profile FROM profile_stores WHERE store = 'S2')
  AND profile NOT IN (SELECT profile FROM profile_stores WHERE store NOT IN ('S1','S2'))
```

Alternatively, use the lesser-known set operators (which give a more easily readable SQL code in my opinion):

```
SELECT profile FROM profile_stores WHERE store = 'S1'
INTERSECT
SELECT profile FROM profile_stores WHERE store = 'S2'
EXCEPT
SELECT profile FROM profile_stores WHERE store NOT IN ('S1', 'S2')
```

In both cases, we start by filtering out only those profiles that are linked to stores 'S1' and 'S2' simultaneously. From this set, we then remove profiles that are also linked to other stores.

Both these set-oriented methods can be easily expanded to a variety of search conditions. For example to find profiles that are linked to any number of stores while not being linked to others (in general, or specific), etc.

Answer (score 0):

another approach

```
select profile from table where store = 's1' 
intersection 
select profile from table where store = 's2' 
except 
select profile from table where store not in ('s1', 's2')
```